# is there select shape event in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have excel Project that includes pictures. I have userform that has ImageBox. This form shows pictures dynamically according to row number with using selection change event.

This event triggered when cell selection change. But i want to triggered this event by clicking on shape. Is there any solution for that?

Please see image.
[image]

These are codes for cell selection change event.

```
Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Pic As Shape
  For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Pic.TopLeftCell.Row = ActiveCell.Row Then
      If Pic.Type = msoPicture Then
         Pic.Select
    
         Dim sheetName As String, MyPicture As String, strPicPath As String
         sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
         MyPicture = Selection.Name

         strPicPath = SavedPictureTo(MyPicture)' This function save image
         Load ImageViever      'ImageViewer is UserForm name

          With ImageViever
          .Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strPicPath)
          .Show vbModeless
         End With
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *is there select shape event in VBA?* Nope, but I think you can assign a macro manually to all shapes when clicked

Comment: Have a look here: [Programmatically assign macro in Excel to multiple shapes in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843684/programmatically-assign-macro-in-excel-to-multiple-shapes-in-a-range)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written in the comments, you can assign a (parameterless) Sub to a shape that is executed when a shape is clicked.

In Excel, you can assign the macro by right-clicking on the shape and select "Assign macro".

With VBA, you write the name of the macro to the `OnAction`-property of the shape:

```
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes  ' <-- Select the sheet(s) you need
    sh.OnAction = "HelloWorld"     ' <-- Change this to the name of your event procedure
Next
```

If you want to know which shape was clicked, you can use the [`Application.Caller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller) property. When the macro was called by clicking on a shape, it contains the name of that shape.

```
Sub helloWorld()
    Dim sh As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "I was not called by clicking on a shape"
    Else
        MsgBox "Someone clicked on " & sh.Name
    End If
End Sub
```